# SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO emp 
VALUES (empno, ename, job, sal, depno, commission) 
VALUES (1, 'satan', 'stripper',  12, 4, NULL);
```

output

```
INSERT INTO emp 
VALUES (empno, ename, job, sal, depno, commission) 
VALUES (1, 'satan', 'stripper',  12, 4, NULL)
                                                                  *
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: What is your problem, could you describe it? conditions, how to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

You have too many instances of the word "values" in there.  Try instead:

```
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, depno, commission) 
VALUES (1, 'satan', 'stripper', 12, 4, NULL);
```